# NPM installation failing after El Capitan update

Tags: node.js, npm, file-permissions, osx-elcapitan

I have a project using many npm packages and some from bower repository. Ever since I have upgraded to OSX El Capitan, running `npm install` is failing and generally I am getting the following error on a lot of packages:

```
Error: Attempt to unlock xxx which hasn't been locked
```

I understand that this has something to do with permissions on /usr/local and subsequent directories. I have tried the following:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

and even this:

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local
```

I also suspected that perhaps this was because of the rootless security feature in El Capitan, so I tried disabling that as well:

```
sudo nvram boot-args="rootless=0"
```

In every attempt, I have tried to delete `node_modules` and `bower_components` directories, did `npm cache clean` and then tried to run `npm install` again. But, I am getting the same error. 
My versions are as follows:

```
System Darwin 15.0.0
command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
cwd /Users/ali786/Desktop/xyz
node -v v0.10.33
npm -v 1.4.28
```

What could be the reason and fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

I have a very similar problem after upgrading from El Capitan I suspect is permission as well.

I removed all of node and npm and upgraded to the latest versions so i't not your versions of node and npm.

node v4.2.1
npm 3.3.9

I'm running 
docker run --rm -v "$PWD":/worker -w /worker iron/node npm install

and it can't find any files that are in the same folder.